# I can't access my Windows machine with xfreerdp

Tags: networking, ssh

My desktop machine is running Windows 7, and my laptop is running Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).  I installed `xfreerdp` on the laptop, and on the desktop I allowed remote access.

I setup port forwarding on my router with port 3389 and the desktop as the host.  I checked the port, and it is open.  However when I try to access the machine with this command from the Ubuntu terminal, I get an error :

```
$ xfreerdp -u myUserName -p myPassword 192.168.1.18
   Error: protocol security negotiation failure.
```

(192.168.1.18 is my desktop's IP address)

I'm pretty new to all of this, so don't assume any prior knowledge.  I've managed to get from the Windows machine to the Linux machine using SSH via PuTTY, but I can't go the other way.

The impetus for this is I am doing a major home addition, and I will be living at a friends house for a month.  However I run a CAD program on the desktop, and I need to be able to design while I'm living in exile.

Thanks in advance for your help

P.S. Nevermind, I guess you can't get into a machine running Windows 7 Home, only Windows 7 Pro, Business, or Enterprise. Maybe Teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

God slution for you is to use VNC. Its free and support win and linux.
You can view more and download from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/download/).
Work fine for me.
VNC use port 5900.